# Count Order of Factor Level Occurance

Tags: r, dplyr

My transactional dataset contains several variables including an ID number, date, and transaction area (factor):

```
    id<-as.integer(rep(c(1,2,3,4,5),times=20))
    date<-rep(seq(as.Date("2011-07-01"),by="day", length.out=100))
    category<-rep(as.factor(letters[seq( from = 1, to = 4 )]),times=25)

    transactions<-data.frame(id, date, category)

    head(transactions)
      id       date category
       1 2011-07-01        a
       2 2011-07-02        b
       3 2011-07-03        c
       4 2011-07-04        d
       5 2011-07-05        a
       1 2011-07-06        b
```

What I would like to do on a per-ID basis is determine the order of the factor appearance without recounting a factor that has already appeared.

```
    solution <- transactions %>%
                group_by(id, date)%>%
                mutate(category_order= (solution))
```

So I can get:

```
     head(transactions)
      id       date category category_order
       1 2011-07-01        a     1
       1 2011-07-06        b     2
       1 2011-07-11        c     3
       1 2011-07-16        d     4
       1 2011-07-21        a     1
       1 2011-07-26        b     2
```

For each ID if a category repeats, it must have the same order value.  In the example above a is always 1st, b is always 2nd, etc.

What I want to do is count the number of times each category is 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. to obtain a frequency distribution for number of times a is 1st, b is 1st, a is 2nd, etc:

```
    head(transactions)
       category category_ order category_order_count
       a     1     5
       a     2     3
       a     3     5
       a     4     4
       b     1     5
       b     2     2
```

It's probably not complicated, but I am having a mental block because it essentially involves counting an order per ID without repeating a factor level, then summarizing per ID, and finally summarizing per category.

Comment: Could you give an example of a dataset plus what the final output would look like when the factors are "out of order"?  Your current example could be solved by `as.numeric(transactions$category)`, but I'm guessing your real situation has some mixing up of the categories.

Comment: Doesn't `table` (or `as.data.frame.table` if the long form is desired) already do what is asked? So I guess my real question is "shouldn't people learn base R before reaching for dplyr/tidyr solutions?"

Comment: My actual dataset is confidential, but identical in data type to what is above.  Perhaps the question is not clear- What I want to do is count the number of times each category is 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc. to obtain a frequency distribution for number of times a is 1st, b is 1st, a is 2nd, etc.  I will edit above.

Comment: @42 no, it does not, which is why I posted the question....

Answer (score 1):

Within each id you could set the levels of the factor to the order they appear within that group and then transform the factors to integers via `as.numeric` to form your new variable.  This relies on the order of the dataset, so if things aren't in order you should `arrange` by id and date.

```
transactions %>%
    arrange(id, date) %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    mutate(category_order = as.numeric(factor(category, levels = unique(category))))
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be also done with `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(transactions)`), grouped by 'id', specify the 'i' part with `order` of 'id' and 'date', convert the 'category' into `factor` by specifying the `levels` as the `unique` elements in 'category', coerce it to 'integer' and assign (`:=`) the output to 'category_order'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(transactions)[order(id, date), category_order := as.integer(factor(category,
            levels = unique(category))) , by = id]

head(transactions)
#   id       date category category_order
#1:  1 2011-07-01        a              1
#2:  2 2011-07-02        b              1
#3:  3 2011-07-03        c              1
#4:  4 2011-07-04        d              1
#5:  5 2011-07-05        a              1
#6:  1 2011-07-06        b              2
```